# Magento Catalog Price Rules

Tags: php, magento, cron, catalog

My catalog price rules consistently fail..

They've failed ever since 1.4.1. I've upgraded to 1.4.2 because some people said that it was fixed, unfortunately for me it wasn't.

Cron runs. Cron job monitor reports various tasks being scheduled and successfully running. Everything except catalog price rules. What is the matter with this thing?

I set my System -> Cron settings to:

```
Generate schedules every: 60
Schedule ahead for: 1
Missed if not run within: 60
History cleanup every: 120
Success history lifetime: 120
Failure history lifetime: 120
```

Update#1. I'm looking at my cronmonitor.php file and I see catalogrule_apply_all was pending as of 1AM. I also see a lot of jobs that were missed.

Update#2. At 2am catalogrule_apply_all disappeared from cronmonitor and I think the history was cleared, so I don't see anything under missed. I'm pretty sure that it was missed.

So, now, how do I prevent it from being missed?

Comment: possible that your DB is not completing or locking the tables and reaching deadlocks , check your exception logs and mysql log to see if this is the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after more digging and investigation, my problem is finally RESOLVED!

Turns out that after updating to 1.4.2, I still had some modified 1.4.1 catalog price rule files in my local mage folder that were preventing the rules from running properly. I deleted those.

After that, I also had to set my Cron schedules in Configuration > System to:

```
Generate Schedules Every: 1
Schedule Ahead for: 15
Missed if Not Run Within: 120
History Cleanup Every: 1440
Success History Lifetime: 1440
Failure History Lifetime: 1440
```

The last three are set to 1440 minutes so that I can see a full 24 hours in my cron monitor.

Now onto the Google Base issue.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you get your favourite IDE setup to debug, and then call `cron.php` from your web browser and step through the code.  You can manually insert entries into the `cron_schedule` table in the database to force cron to execute a particular cronjob such as `catalogrule_apply_all`.  Set a breakpoint inside `Mage_CatalogRule_Model_Observer::dailyCatalogUpdate($observe)` and trace it through.

That should allow you to isolate the problem and (hopefully) resolve.